# Graphics tablet/stylus library

Tags: c#, .net, input

Does anyone know of any libraries for .net that allow you to use graphics tablets?

specifically i am after the pressure sensitivity of the pen, but the 'eraser' and buttons on the pen would be useful too.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the source for [Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net)

**EDIT**: There should also be a DLL there...

Answer (score 2):

I have also discovered that WPF also has an `InkCanvas`, which has everything built into it.

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/vbtablet/
It worked for me. At least for a while. Now I'm having some problems with it, and trying to find another one. If my search fails, I'm going to use the Windows API directly.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's RealTimeStylus API gives access to all pen/stylus data.